# Код для дискорд бота, что бы он выдавал рандомую фразу из списка Python

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Сам пытался не получилось, можете кто то написать такой код, буду благодарен. Python

Comment: `random.choice(['раз', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Подключайте библиотеку random `import random`

После этого я просто с помощью двух вспомогательных функций брал из файла фразы:

```
def read_file(self, filename):
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as fl:
        sp = fl.readlines()
    return sp

def random_choose_phrase(self, sp):
    phrase = random.choice(sp)
    return phrase
```

Пример как это выглядело в основном коде:

```
elif text == 'расскажи что-нибудь умное' or text == 'расскажи факт' or text == 'поумничай':
    response = self.random_choose_phrase(self.read_file('phrases/facts.txt'))
    await message.channel.send(response)
```

В вашем случае функция read_file не требуется и просто sp заменяется на ваш список.

Comment: Cпасибо большое.